# Tuning Hyper Parameters ALS Model

Tags: scala, apache-spark-ml, matrix-factorization

I'm working on tuning an implicit ALS model.  Of the hyper parameters: rank, maxiter, regParam, alpha, numItemBlocks, numUserBlocks, are there any key ones which generally improve accuracy the most?  Are there ranges of values that are known to work well?  I'm working in scala is there a gridsearch process that is generally used, (I'm more familiar with python.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents :

Of these three hyperparameters, rank is the most important one as that determines the latent factors that will be used for modeling the product and user features. In my experience, values between 50-200 work well for almost all cases. Going above 200 becomes overkill.

Since ALS converges quite quickly, there is usually no need to change the maxiter parameter beyond a value. Value of 200 should be enough for most of your datasets unless your regularization parameter (regparam) is high. In such cases, you might need more.

The default value for regparam which is 0.1 works well for most of the cases, no need to change that. You can do a gridsearch on this parameter to be sure if you wish.